# Is there a way that can move a the camera to a point on the map view on Android?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

As we know, `val targetLocation = LatLng(latitude, longitude) val update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(targetLocation) map?.animateCamera(update)`
will move the `targetLocation` to the center of the map view.

But I want to move the `targetLocation` to special pixel point on the map view.
Is there is way to implement this feature?

I have tried many ways but I still can't resolve this problem.